# Modal/dialog for login/signup for an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web, frontend

I'm trying to implement a login/signin dialog for my app (something like that of [Medium](https://medium.com/)) I have searched a lot about it online and I think I will go with the $modal from angular ui-bootstrap. I'm wondering if someone can direct me to a tutorial for making something like that using $model. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal
<< Contains code examples. Markup and Javascript. Start here.

http://www.nganimate.org/
<< This can help create an intro transition effect similar to Medium's login thing.

Here's a start (Fill in the blanks, write your modal html + controller):

index.html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .login-intro.ng-enter { /*starting css properties. Transparency, position etc*/ }
    .login-intro.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { /*final css properties. The ngAnimate will transition these for you*/ }
</style>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <a href="#" ng-click="main.openLoginModal()">Log in / Sign up</a>
</div>
```

main-controller.js:

```
(
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
myModule.controller('MainCtrl as main', function($modal){

    var controller = this;

    controller.openLoginModal = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'login-template.html',
            controller: 'LoginController as login'
        };

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            // Redirect to the logged-in area of your site
        }, function () {
            // optional function. Do something if the user cancels.
        });
});



})();
```

login-template.html:

```
<div ng-view class="login-intro">
    <!--login inputs, buttons etc here-->
</div>
```

Comment: can you please help me out her, i have followed exact instructions, but dialog box not popup. "ui.bootstrap is active"
i have placed main-controller.js code into app.js and index.html code into my header.html directive.

Comment: Hi @m-t, this isn't enough information to help. I suggest creating a new question with more details and your code. It's not clear to me what you mean by "i have placed main-controller.js code into app.js and index.html code into my header.html directive". It's probably just the wording you're using, but either way more information would help.

Comment: Thank for your reply @HankScorpio. and apologies that information is not clear. if i open the same question that would have been duplicate of the this query and i want exact response "on login/signup" button click popup form appear. is there's any way to send you direct question.

Comment: asked the question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500224/login-signup-modal-for-yeoman-angular-generator-app

Please guide me accordingly thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this may not answer your question directly but I have done login modal dialog using ngDialog (https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) with similar functionality as the Medium site. You may want to look into ngDialog.